# Improve accuracy of underlined text

Tags: image-processing, tesseract

Some underlines in my image are very close to the text. For that particular text tesseract is unable to produce accurate results. I have attached the image and text file. Is there any way i can increase accuracy of the text?

I have tried to remove the underlines with some of the image processing techniques, but the problem is those lines which are close to the text are not getting removed.

And are there any parameters in tesseract which i can use to improve the accuracy? Thanks in advance.

[image which i am trying to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9fdB.png)

Its Result:

ARR!

D.

1.

\OCIJHJO‘LI'IJ?‘
3..

10.

E.

F.

SITE NUMBER

ARCHEOLOGICAL DESCRIPTION

General site description SITE IS COVERED WITH LARGE PINES AND IS IN RELATIVLY
GOOD CONDITION, snowING'EITTrE‘SIGNS‘OFTRosmN—EXCEPT—AEONG-Tmm
_"—""NHERE IT DROPS or INTO FLOODPLAIN OF CREEK THERE ARE A EEN ANIMAL TRAILS THAT

HAVE APPARENTLY ERODED OUT IN THE PAST. ONE OF THESE WAS QUIET DEEP ACCORDING
“TO AUGER TEST, BUT HAS FILLED UP WITH SAND AND GROWN OVER AGAIN. FIRST AUGER TEST

“WAS INTO THIS DEE P"GULLY" AND GAVE A FALSE IMPRESSION AS TO THE TRUE DEPTH OF

SITE. THIS TEST HOLE PRODUCED LIEHLQ FLAKES ALL THE WAY DOWN TO 42 INCHES AND
_m STERILE SAND DOWN TO 60 INCHES= REST OF SITE PRODUCED SAND AND CHIPS ONLY TO
l- an I ' A: : I L I i : ‘5!) THIS 3 1.0 5.- 3.. 'Y __
FINE SITE.
Site size .AT L S - E Y CONSIDERABLY MQBE
Nature of archeological deposition EAIBIEIHNDESTURBED EXCEPT ALONG THE EDGES OF SITE
T D0.
Site depth. 20-22 INCHES
Hidden
Faunal preservation
Floral preservation
Human remains
Cultural features (type and number)
Charcoal preservation
DATA RECOVERY METHODS
Ground surface visibility: 0% x 1-251 26—50% 51-75% 76—100%

Description of ground cover iMATURE PINE FOREST

Time spent collecting Number of peeple collecting
Description of surface collecting methods

Type and extent of testing and/or excavation FIVE TEST HOLES WERE SUNK IN SITE WITH 8"

AUGERa THESE WERE TAKEN DOWN IN 6" LEVELS UNTIL STERILE CLAY WAS REACHED. DIRTTA T-
FROM EACH 6" LEVEL WAS SCREENED THROUGH_l/4" WIRE MESH AND ARTIFACTS KEPT FOR

ANALYSIS. ALL TEST HOLES QERE PLQIIED EIIE TRANSIT IN RELATION TO DATUM MARKER
WHI IS A PIPE ‘ _ -: ﬂ' : 3:0. . .: U' J I: : : . *!" uFF 3L*
GROUND. P__\l: IS I : um \I' :i “I ' I ' .M' I ' D' . I’ I 2! ti 0 .1. ' -. _ .L l' .

ARCHEOLOGICAL COMPONENTS

Paleo-Indian Late Whodland 17th century

Early Archaic Mississippian 18th century

Middle Archaic Late prehistoric 19th century

Late Archaic Unknown prehistoric ___ 20th century __
Early Woodland Ceramic prehistoric ____ Unknown historic

Middle Woodland 16th century

Comment: Did you try to [dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate) your image with a small 3x3 kernel? So you can produce a "larger" gap between line and text?

Comment: @DanielAlbertini I didn't tried that but, [line removal algorithm](http://leptonica.com/line-removal.html) of leptonica worked for me.